# A sleeping mcu in a product -sent by air to?

Tags: microcontroller, batteries, pcb-design, production

This might be strange, but i guess you guys electrical engineers are the only one that knows that .

Our MCU is turned on by a push button . That means he sleeps most of the time, and when pushing the button he awakes up with interrupt .

The only concerns are :

1. sending products that are in sleep mode, means- a little current is flow, is it safe in an airplane ? is it "professional" ? will it makes troubles in shipping? can a battery be connected to a product at all ?

2.If your products (pcb's) are sitting on the shelf for a while, that means your battery is going down, not too much , but it take some current .
Is this, again "professional" to do? are you as hardware engineers design a circuit like this to be sent do another country ?

The mcu on sleep will take about 100uA , and the battery is 500mAH .

thanks .

Comment: What battery type is it? There are lots of regulations especially for lithium batteries

Comment: sorry , didn't mention, lithium polymer ... so what engineers do? you cant let a consumer connect them by himself, its not like AAA or coin cell..

Comment: LiPo needs to be very strictly engineered in and UL-type approved to be allowed on an airplane. That's one. As for storage, a LiPo _can_ drain out in a year by itself, 100uA or not, so statistically your sleeping MCU will only double your problem, not cause it. Also, an MCU in sleep that uses 100uA is thirsty for modern sleep-enabled-applications, just saying.

Comment: thanks, so just out of curiosity , every package with a battery was approved by someone ? think of all the Kickstarter products running now, i guess some amateur engineers designed them and i guess they never invested money in getting approvals from anyone, so how you actually send products with batteries ?

Comment: @Asmyldof can you cite the relevant standard?

Comment: https://www.ups.com/media/news/en/ca/intl_lithium_battery_regulations.pdf, just skipped over it, seems like a good starting point.

Comment: A lot of people add a thin plastic strip to isolate the battery in the holder.  This can be routed through a small slit or where the battery door meets the case.  Then on the outside there's a bright colored pull tab.  The user just pulls it out in first use.  Maybe that won't work for you but some one time mechanical method could keep your battery from draining.  I can't speak to safety :)

Comment: @Daniel What Arsenal linked is basically what I'm getting at. Because badly designed LiPo has been proven to be explosive, transporters only use airtransport for devices of known and tested sources if it is known to contain batteries. Also think about travelling yourself: "All batteries need to be in their original packaging or inside the consumer product they are meant for". -- As for hobbyists shipping stuff everywhere, that happens. They will not inspect every package, but if they do, you risk a fine or package destruction.

Comment: @Asmyldof all of what you wrote here is about lithium only ? if for example its an  AAA batteries , there is no problem at all ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many products are shipped worldwide with batteries already installed and connected.  One example off the top of my head is the Motorola Moto G 3rd generation cellphone, where the battery is not removable.  Most iPhones are the same way - the battery is permanently installed and not designed to be removed by the consumer.

Same with other devices such as wristwatches.